# PIL returns empty boxes instead of images

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a program in Python 3 using PIL and am having hard time displaying image...

I am using dictionaries to temporarily store variables from config.ini

```
usernames={}
usericons={}
for i in range(numberOfUsers):
    usernames[i]=config[str(i)]["username"]
    usericons[i]=config[str(i)]["usericon"]
```

Later, I want to display a grid with images(thumbnails) and usernames for user to select from

```
usericonWidgets={}

for i in range(numberOfUsers):
    usericons[i]=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(config[str(i)]["usericon"]))
    usericonWidgets[i]=Label(usersSelectionCanvas,borderwidth=2,relief=SOLID,)
    usericonWidgets[i].configure(image=usericons[i])
    usericonWidgets[i].grid(row=i,column=0)
```

However, I keep getting empty square where the images should be...
No errors appear, just white boxes... What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: If `usericons` is temporary variable try to save references to images: `usericonWidgets[i].image = usericons[i]`

Comment: it returns `KeyError: 0`

Comment: Sorry, I implemented your code incorrectly... It works perfectly. Thank you @kalgasnik

Comment: Read this for explanation: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm